# Cypress: how to compare diffrent datatypes concatinated with String/ text read out from tables

Tags: html, compare, cypress, distinct-values, complex-data-types

I want to compare double-values (75.999)  mixed with text: 75.999 & edit

I got this values from a table and tried to parse it to string, to replace all sign and characters except digits, but nothing worked.

HTML-SNIPET:

```
<td data-cy="project.chanceOrder" class="text-right editableRow" aria-label="project.chanceOrder: NCDd_3wB0UC4Ud30l6iP">
    <div class="ng-star-inserted">
        <span class="ng-star-inserted">75.999&nbsp;%&nbsp;</span>
        <!---->
        <a class="inlineEditLink" title="Bearbeiten">
            <em class="material-icons">edit</em>
        </a>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <!---->
</td>
```

Cypress-Code (NOT working):

```
cy.get('[data-cy="projectList"]')
.find('[data-cy="project.chanceOrder"]')
.each((MyElement, MyIndex, MyContentOfArray) => {
    if(MyIndex == 0)
    {
        // NOT WORKING
        expect(parseFloat(MyElement.text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, ""))).to.equal(project.chanceOrder.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, ""))

        // NOT WORKING
        // let tmp = MyElement.text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")
        // let OriginValueToCompare = '' + project.chanceOrder
        // let tmpStr = OriginValueToCompare.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")
        // expect(tmp).to.equal(tmpStr)

        // NOT WORKING
        // expect(MyElement.text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")).to.equal(project.chanceOrder.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, ""))

        // NOT WORKING
        expect(MyElement.text()).to.equal('' + project.chanceOrder+" % edit")
        
        // NOT WORKING
        let tmp1 = "" + MyElement.text()
        let tmp2 = "" + project.chanceOrder +" % edit"
        if(tmp1 == tmp2)
        {
            cy.log("=============== YES =====================================")

        }
        
        // NOT WORKING
        cy.wrap(tmp1).should('eq', tmp2);
        
        // NOT WORKING
        cy.wrap(tmp1).should('have.text', tmp2);
})
```

ERROR-Message (ALWAYS):

expected 75.999 % edit to equal 75.999 % edit

If I compare the output from cypress Log  with notepad++

75.999 % edit    <->    75.999 % edit

it always says, that the two files matches.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```js
expect(MyElement.text()).to.contain('75.999')
```

This will check that the string `75.999` is present in your extracted text.